# Linking typeclasses, classes, and instances

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to write a combinatorial game theory engine in Haskell. There are a few key elements.

- Any environment should have 3 behaviors: the ability to produce a "base" state, the ability to advance state given an action, and the ability to produce a numeric reward vector. I've used a typeclass `Environment` to do this.
- Specific games (e.g. Nim below) should be instances of `Environments`. I'm using this abstraction because I'll want to write functions (e.g. Monte Carlo Tree Search) that require the `Environment` typeclass, not any specific game.

To test out that I have it all right, I've written the below tracer program for the game of Nim.

```
class Environment e where
    baseState :: e -> s
    nextState :: e -> s -> a -> s
    reward :: (Num r) => e -> s -> a -> [r]


data Game = Game { players :: Int
                 , initial_piles :: [Int]
                 } deriving (Show)

data State = State { player :: Int
                   , piles :: [Int]} deriving (Show)

instance Environment Game where
    baseState game = State{player=0, piles=initial_piles game}
    nextState game state action = State{player=0, piles=piles state}
    reward game state action = [0, 0]

newGame :: Int -> [Int] -> Game
newGame players piles = Game{players=players, initial_piles=piles}


main = do
    print "Hello, world!"
    let game = newGame 2 [3,4,5]
    print game
```

When I attempt to compile, I get the following error indicating an issue with my understanding of typeclasses and instances:

```
randm@soundgarden:~/Projects/games/src/Main$ ghc -o basic basic.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( basic.hs, basic.o )

basic.hs:15:22: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘s’ with actual type ‘State’
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          baseState :: forall s. Game -> s
        at basic.hs:15:5-13
    • In the expression: State {player = 0, piles = initial_piles game}
      In an equation for ‘baseState’:
          baseState game = State {player = 0, piles = initial_piles game}
      In the instance declaration for ‘Environment Game’
    • Relevant bindings include
        baseState :: Game -> s (bound at basic.hs:15:5)
   |
15 |     baseState game = State{player=0, piles=initial_piles game}
   |                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

basic.hs:16:35: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘s’ with actual type ‘State’
      ‘s’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          nextState :: forall s a. Game -> s -> a -> s
        at basic.hs:16:5-13
    • In the expression: State {player = 0, piles = piles state}
      In an equation for ‘nextState’:
          nextState game state action
            = State {player = 0, piles = piles state}
      In the instance declaration for ‘Environment Game’
    • Relevant bindings include
        state :: s (bound at basic.hs:16:20)
        nextState :: Game -> s -> a -> s (bound at basic.hs:16:5)
   |
16 |     nextState game state action = State{player=0, piles=piles state}
   |                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't want to insert too many class constraints into the `Environment` definition, other than the reward being numeric. How do I fix the above skeleton without losing this flexibility?

Comment: `class Environment e where baseState :: e -> s` means that from an environment `e` it must be possible to construct absolutely any type `s`, chosen by whoever calls `baseState`. If `s` is instead chosen by the instance, then you should be using either type families or functional dependencies.

Comment: By the way, classes are not the only way to structure this kind of code. For example, when I implemented MCTS, I used [a record](https://github.com/dmwit/nurse-sveta/blob/225e32eacbae6d65ec8b336ffe7e927cf9e17355/src/Dr/Mario/Sveta/MCTS.hs#L23-L64). The two approaches have various tradeoffs.

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the fields of the record are the methods in the typeclass?

Comment: @MikeRand: That’s right, essentially it’s passing around the typeclass dictionary/vtable explicitly, representing the instance as a value. This is sometimes referred to as the “scrap your typeclasses” technique, I believe after [the eponymous article by Gabriel Gonzales](https://www.haskellforall.com/2012/05/scrap-your-type-classes.html), although the technique itself is older/folklore. I generally prefer it by default nowadays unless I need typeclass-specific features, namely: overloading, type-level sets/relations, and static global uniqueness/coherence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind both `e` and `s`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class Environment e s where
    baseState :: e -> s
    nextState :: e -> s -> a -> s
    reward :: (Num r) => e -> s -> a -> [r]


data Game = Game { players :: Int
                 , initial_piles :: [Int]
                 } deriving (Show)

data State = State { player :: Int
                   , piles :: [Int]} deriving (Show)

instance Environment Game State where
    baseState game = State{player=0, piles=initial_piles game}
    nextState game state action = State{player=0, piles=piles state}
    reward game state action = [0, 0]

newGame :: Int -> [Int] -> Game
newGame players piles = Game{players=players, initial_piles=piles}


main = do
    print "Hello, world!"
    let game = newGame 2 [3,4,5]
    print game
```

Comment: ...and when the time comes to actually implement `nextState` correctly, I suspect they'll want to add `a` to the class head as well.

Comment: Yes, and also `r`, because in single-person problems, `r` is commonly a scalar (e.g. cost). Is it a code smell that I require a language extension to do this? In reading about  MPTC, it seems I should also read up on functional dependencies to ensure I'm not naively doing anything ambiguous.

Comment: @MikeRand: No, language extensions are just opt-in features. They were originally meant to allow compilers to add new features before they were added to the Haskell standard, but since GHC is the only compiler in widespread use and a new edition of the standard isn’t forthcoming, the chief benefit of language flags is just to be explicit and make features searchable. (Although naturally some are considered more benign or more experimental than others.)