# Resolving ambiguity in MultiParameterTypeClass

Tags: haskell

Based on the feedback to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66500323/linking-typeclasses-classes-and-instances), I've used a MultiParamTypeClass to represent a reinforcement learning environment `Environment`, using 3 type variables: `e` for the environment instance itself (e.g. a game like Nim, below), `s` for the state data type used by the specific game, and `a` for the action data type used by the specific game.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}

class MultiAgentEnvironment e s a where
    baseState :: e -> s
    nextState :: e -> s -> a -> s
    reward :: (Num r) => e -> s -> a -> [r]

data Game = Game { players :: Int
                 , initial_piles :: [Int]
                 } deriving (Show)

data State = State { player :: Int
                   , piles :: [Int]} deriving (Show)

data Action = Action { removed :: [Int]} deriving (Show)

instance MultiAgentEnvironment Game State Action where
    baseState game = State{player=0, piles=initial_piles game}
    nextState game state action = State{player=player state + 1 `mod` players game,
                                        piles=zipWith (-) (piles state) (removed action)}
    reward game state action = [0, 0]

newGame :: Int -> [Int] -> Game
newGame players piles = Game{players=players, initial_piles=piles}


main = do
    print "Hello, world!"
    let game = newGame 2 [3,4,5]
    print game
```

As expected, I'm running into ambiguity issues already. See below, where the action type variable `a` is deemed ambiguous within the typeclass `Environment`.

```
(base) randm@soundgarden:~/Projects/games/src/Main$ ghc -o basic basic.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( basic.hs, basic.o )

basic.hs:4:5: error:
    • Could not deduce (MultiAgentEnvironment e s a0)
      from the context: MultiAgentEnvironment e s a
        bound by the type signature for:
                   baseState :: forall e s a. MultiAgentEnvironment e s a => e -> s
        at basic.hs:4:5-23
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘baseState’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method:
        baseState :: forall e s a. MultiAgentEnvironment e s a => e -> s
      In the class declaration for ‘MultiAgentEnvironment’
  |
4 |     baseState :: e -> s
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

How do I resolve this ambiguity? Am I mistakenly using typeclasses to implement interfaces (i.e. `baseState`, `nextState`, `reward`)?

Comment: Have you tried enabling `AllowAmbiguousTypes` like the error message suggests?

Comment: It works, but as I'm learning Haskell I'm generally hesitant to do so without understanding why it isn't the default setting, especially given documented warnings about naively using MPTC and the ambiguity that results.

Comment: The reason it's not the default is just that it wasn't part of the standard last time the standard was officially set. New features appeared since that time, and GHC has chosen to make them opt-in rather than just dump them on you indiscriminately. Extensions are not "extra" or "scary" or "not quite Haskell", they're just features that appeared more recently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you could turn on `AllowAmbiguousTypes`, that will only push your problem further down the road.  That is, eventually, you'll try to call `baseState`, and GHC will need to know what `a` is.  There are three good options you have:

1. Use functional dependencies,
2. Use associated type families, or
3. Don't use a class for this.

Let's look at each option in detail.

---

#### Functional Dependencies

The problem that GHC is having is that it knows which `e` and `s` you want to use when you call a function like `baseState` (it can determine those from the input and output of the `baseState` function), but it doesn't know which `a` to use.  For all GHC knows, there may be multiple instantiations of `MultiAgentEnvironment` that could work for a given `e` and `s`.  With functional dependencies, you can tell GHC that a given `e` and `s` totally define what the `a` should be.  In plain English, by putting in a functional dependency on `a`, you're saying that for any given environment and state, there is only one possible action type that makes sense.  If this is true, then you add them like so:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}

class MultiAgentEnvironment e s a | e s -> a where
    baseState :: e -> s
    nextState :: e -> s -> a -> s
    reward :: (Num r) => e -> s -> a -> [r]
```

Since each one of your functions have `e` and `s` in them, `a` is the only type parameter that could have been ambiguous, and with this fundep, it's not ambiguous anymore.  That said, if *you* know that the environment type determines *both* the state and action unambiguously (that is, a given environment can only ever have one possible state and action type), then you can use *two* fundeps to lower the ambiguity even more, as in:

```hs
class MultiAgentEnvironment e s a | e -> s a where
```

---

#### Associated Type Families

Functional Dependencies have a bit of a bad reputation, and the more modern alternative is typically to use *associated type families*.  In practice, for your purposes, they work very similarly.  Once again, you have to be okay with the environment type determining the action type (and, perhaps, the state type).  If so, you write it like this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

class MultiAgentEnvironment e where
    type EState  e
    type EAction e
    baseState :: e -> EState e
    nextState :: e -> EState e -> a -> EState e
    reward :: (Num r) => e -> EState e -> EAction e -> [r]
```

Then, when you create your instance, it will look like:

```hs
instance MultiAgentEnvironment Game where
    type EState  Game = State
    type EAction Game = Action
    baseState game = State{player=0, piles=initial_piles game}
    nextState game state action = ...
```

---

#### Use a Data Type Instead Of a Class

The last option is to forgo using a type class altogether.  Instead, you can make the data explicit by just representing it as a data type.  For instance, you can define:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

data MultiAgentEnvironment e s a = MultiAgentEnvironment
  { baseState :: e -> s
  , nextState :: e -> s -> a -> s
  , reward :: forall r. (Num r) => e -> s -> a -> [r]
  }
```

Instead of making an instance of the type class, you just make a value of the data type:

```hs
gameStateActionMAE :: MultiAgentEnvironment Game State Action
gameStateActionMAE = MultiAgentEnvironment
  { baseState = \game -> State{player=0, piles=initial_piles game}
  , nextState = \game state action -> State{player=player state + 1 `mod` players game,
                                        piles=zipWith (-) (piles state) (removed action)}
  , reward = \game state action -> [0, 0]
  }
```

One nice advantage of this method is that you can make multiple different `MultiAgentEnvironment`s with the same types but that have different behaviors.  Using them is pretty simple too: instead of having `MultiAgentEnvironment e s a` as a constraint, you now have it as just a regular old argument.  In fact, if you turn on the `RecordWildCards` pragma, then any function that used to start with

```hs
foo :: MultiAgentEnvironment e s a => x -> y
foo x = ...
```

can now be written as

```hs
foo :: MultiAgentEnvironment e s a -> x -> y
foo mae@MultiAgentEnvironment{..} x = ...
```

and the body should be pretty much identical (well, unless the body calls a subfunction which requires the `MultiAgentEnvironment`, in which case you'll need to manually pass `mae` along).

Comment: Now that I see the record version in detail, it makes more sense. I can actually use closure and a `newGame` method with the former `game` fields as arguments, allowing me to eliminate `game` from the methods themselves.